# .htaccess file redirecing incorrectly

Tags: apache, .htaccess

After creating a dev site on a new server the htaccess file is redirecting links incorrectly. For example if clicking on the link example.com/test from example.com it is trying to redirect to example.com/example.com/test. How can I correct the htaccess file below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Turn on the Rewrite Engine
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    # If the file or directory exists, show it
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Blank queries get sent to the index
    RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]

    # All other queries get sent to the index as index.php/whatever
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
```

Comment: What happens when you type `http://www.example.com/test` in the browser?

Comment: probably you have `href="example.com/test"` in HTML

Comment: @Deadooshka, I think that you may be right. Is there anyway to adjust the .htaccess to remove this duplicate?

Comment: Then you need to change HTML to `href="/test"`

Comment: The problem is that this is a dev site that is mean to be a clone. Changing beyond the htaccess file would be bad practice as it would lead to different code. Additionally there are hundreds of thousands of lines of code that I would prefer not to touch for this.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteBase` to redirect `/example.com/test` to `/test`:

```
RewriteRule ^example\.com/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```